# converging sequence proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I got stuck on one proof on our study guide for real analysis. We use Rudin as our main text.

let $\{A_n\}_{n\geq1}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n\to \infty} A_{2n} = L = \lim_{n\to \infty} A_{2n+1}$.

Show that $A_n$ is convergent.

My idea: so a sequence is convergent if all subsequences converge to the same element. The sequence of every odd term converges, as does the sequence of every even term.

So we can use this to bound the definition of convergent. "For any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $d(A_n, A) < \epsilon$".

however. I have yet to be able to pull the algebra out correctly.

Comment: The $\epsilon - \delta$ stuff can be stated this way : $\lim _{n\to \infty}x_n=x \iff $ for every nbhd $S$ of $x$, the set $\{n\in N: x_n\not \in S\}$ is finite. This is often easier to work with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $\epsilon>0$. There are $N_1,N_2$ such that for all $n>N_1$, $d(A_{2n},L)<\epsilon$ and for all $n>N_2$, $d(A_{2n+1},L)<\epsilon$.
Let $N=max\{2N_1,2N_2+1\}$. Then, for all $n>N$, $d(A_n,L)<\epsilon$. So, $A_n\to L$.

Comment: why is your N=max{2N1,2N2+1} and not N = Max{N1, N2}

Comment: Because this way, $n>N$ implies if $n=2k+1$, then $2k+1>N\ge2N_2+1$, i.e. $k>N_2$. And if $n=2k$, then $2k>N\ge2N_1$, i.e. $k>N_1$

Comment: AH i see. that's brilliant